# Error payload exceeded 1 mb on Select box click

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux

there.
I have very weird error from payload in console.
Which i strugle to understand and fix.
When i try to change a value in select box.
And click on select box, i recieve warning which says

```
Error: payload exceeded 1MB limit
    at Object._$jsonPayload_21.event
```

Although app doesn't crash, it just throws error in console.

And the wierdest part is that i dont even change value in select box, i just click on it not
selecting yet a value.

Also i forgot to mention that i recieve employees from Redux, but error trigers when i click on  Select element.

I never faced this error previously, if anyone knows how to fix it or what may be wrong here, i would be very gratefull.

```
      <Select
        onChange={(e) => { concole.log(e)  }}
      >
        {
          employees.map(employee => {
            if (employee.works === true) {
              return <Option key={employee.id} value={employee.name}>{employee.name}</Option>
            } else {
              return null
            }
          })
        }
      </Select>
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's a lot of employees?

Comment: @Andrew Corrigan no only two

Comment: Hmmm, that is weird

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan But those 2 employees have indeed a lot of data inside

Comment: That'll be your issue, try getting that data in smaller chunks